# opacidad para fondo de div y no para el contenido

Tags: css

Buenas noches
Tengo un div con un background-image pero quiero ponerle opacity (al menos su efecto) para esa imagen. Si se lo pongo al div, la opacidad afecta a todo lo que ponga en él. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin modificar la imagen?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida. Podrías compartir el código con el que estás intentando resolver el problema ?

Comment: Creo que hay una pregunta parecida que se hizo con anterioridad, voy a buscarla y pongo el enlace. Buscando "opacidad fondo" (sin las comillas) encuentré un par de resultados que pueden ser útiles: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49431/c%C3%B3mo-opacar-imagen-de-fondo-al-cambiar-el-tama%C3%B1o-de-pantalla/49441#49441 o https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50073/c%C3%B3mo-a%C3%B1adir-color-con-transparencia-sobre-el-background

Answer (score 2):

Si entendi bien, creo que quieres hacer algo como esto...

```
div {width: 500px; height: 500px; display: block; position: relative;}
div::after {content: ""; background: url(image.jpg); opacity: 0.5; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; position: absolute; z-index: -1; }
```

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer lo que quieres, puedes utilizar la propiedad `::before` de `CSS`.

En el `::before` podrás mostrar la imagen y aplicar la opacidad que quieres sin afectar al div.

Este es un ejemplo:

```css
body
{
  background: url(//image.freepik.com/free-vector/triangular-background_23-2147508098.jpg) center center;
  
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.myDiv {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 400%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.myDiv::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url(//files.ctctcdn.com/77be3546001/91b996da-b256-4ec5-9a6e-5bf92c3922d0.jpg) center center;
    opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
    Hello, I am a DIV :)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que proceses la imagen con Photoshop y le pongas la opacidad que quieras y la guardes como PNG que conserve el valor alpha (transparencia), a nivel sintáctico es más limpio.

Si no te gusta esta opción podrías crear dos  una para el fondo y una para el texto, y dar distintas "class" a cada div, y con CSS opacity: 0.5; a la del fondo.